# MMC and Eventvwr Won't Run on 32-bit Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, mmc

Situation: Windows 8 Release Preview on 32-bit hardware.

Problem:The Eventvwr won't run.  Tried double-clicking actual executable in \System32.  Tried 'Run as Administrator'.

I looked at the underlying MMC.exe, that won't run either.  Run as administrator causes the UAC to fire up with: Publisher: 'Unknown'.  But then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information, the fact that UAC is saying the publisher is unknown sounds like you might have corrupted system files.

Try opening an administrator command prompt and typing `sfc /scannow`

FMI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFC_Scan

Comment: Can I draw the inferrence that MMC and Eventview work correctly on your Windows 8 32-bit system?

Comment: @GuyThomas yes, they work perfectly on my Windows 8 system (though it's x64, but I don't think that should matter O.O)

Comment: Genius answer, I would never have thought of corruption.  I rean SFC and it clearly showed in the LOG hash error for the MMC file.